# Visual Studio 2010 keeps changing my default browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Opera is my browser of choice, so it's set as system default browser. But for debugging web apps in Visual Studio I prefer IE so I set it as default in File-Browse With...
What's weird here is that Visual Studio 2010 keeps changing its default browser to system default in an unknown manner (VS restart is one of the situations).
Is there a way to persist this setting?

**Update:**
The fine folks from [World of VS](http://www.wovs.com) have created a Visual Studio extension called [World of VS Default Browser Switcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921) out of [Scott Hanselman's code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx), which is still not a solution, but a solid workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx

Comment: I've read it already, but what I'm searching for is a permanent solution to the problem, not just a handy toolbar button to switch it back when it occurs. Thanks anyway.