# How to set IE as default browser for mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have set IE as my default browser but when I run the ASP.Net MVC3 application it opens by default *IN* Mozilla Firefox. How can I set that when I run the MVC3 application so it opens in IE by default instead?

Comment: You want to set IE as the default browser in your operating system?

Comment: So @sandeep, when will you ever accept any answer to any of your questions?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running the application from within Visual Studio you can right-click an html/aspx file outside of the Views directory and select 'Browse With'. From here you can change the browser that your app will launch with when you run the app from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the default for only a single application. You set the defaults for protocols. In this case, you want to set the default for `http`. The easiest way is to go into IE, goto the options menu (gear) > Internet Options > Programs tab > Set IE as the default

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this question, and while the other answers helped to a point, I found myself without any aspx pages in my mvc app.

Changing the default browser through internet settings didn't work, so in the end, I added a web form manually, right-clicked in and selected 'Browse With' and then was able to set the default from there.

Comment: I added an extra HTML-page `DummyPageForEasyBrowserSwitch.html`, sick, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently from Visual Studio 2012 and up, you can choose it in the toolbar:

[image: choose browser in Visual Studio toolbar]

As explained in [Visual Studio 2010 keeps changing my default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316606/visual-studio-2010-keeps-changing-my-default-browser):
In earlier versions, you could use a Visual Studio extension called [World of VS Default Browser Switcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921) , as a solid workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool where you can view your application either in IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc. Check it here: [How to view your MVC Application in different browsers](http://onehappycoder.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-view-your-mvc-application-in.html)